# Can't render nested relationship in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

The problem is I have a 'details' field which should render into a nested relationship with it's parent serializer. I have tried a bunch of stuff and nothing seems to be working.

Here's my models:

```
class BusinessOrderModel(OrderToModel):
    reference = models.IntegerField()
    business_num = models.ForeignKey('BusinessModel', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.reference)
    
class BusinessModel(models.Model):
    Business_num = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Business_num)

class DetailModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    detail = models.TextField()
    order = models.ForeignKey('BusinessOrderModel', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and here's my serializers which aren't working:

```
class DetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DetailModel
        fields = ('id', 'detail')

class BusinessOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    details = DetailSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = BusinessOrderModel
        fields = ('reference', 'business_num', 'details')
```

I've tried many different things but I get this error:

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `details`
> on serializer `BusinessOrderSerializer`. The serializer field might be
> named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the
> `BusinessOrderModel` instance. Original exception text was:
> 'BusinessOrderModel' object has no attribute 'details'.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `details` to lookup reverse relationships only works if you set it as the `related_name`. The default for `BusinessOrderModel` to `DetailModel` will be `detailmodel_set`.

To make it accessible by calling `details` you should make this change:

```
class DetailModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    detail = models.TextField()
    order = models.ForeignKey('BusinessOrderModel', related_name="details", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now you can use `DetailModel.objects.get(id=1).details.all()`

You can also customize the query in your serializer:

```
class BusinessOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    details = SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = BusinessOrderModel
        fields = ('reference', 'business_num', 'details')

    def get_details(self, obj):
        return DetailSerializer(obj.details.filter(), many=True).data
```